# How to get total number of record in the query using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my code

```
$attendanceDetail = $this->common->getWhere('tbl_attendance', 'date', $allDate);
$total = $attendanceDetail->num_rows();
if($total >0 )
{
    echo "record found";
}
else{
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

How to get a total number of record in the query result?

Comment: well, I'm assuming $attendanceDetail returns the DB query, so $total will return the number of rows.

Comment: Have you customize the database thing, because there is no such thing ```getWhere``` in codeigniter

Comment: we created an own function in the "common" controller "getWhere" is my function name from that controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$attendanceDetail = $this->common->getWhere('tbl_attendance', 'date', $allDate);
$total = count($attendanceDetail);
if($total >0 )
{
   echo "record found";
}
else{
    echo "Not Found";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Put this method in your Model

```
public function count_records($table_name) {
     return $this->db->count_all($table_name);
}
```

`count_all` is query builder class method which returns total no of records in a table see [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results)

and inside your controller method use it like this:

```
$total_records = $this->your_model->count_records('put_table_name_here');
```